# How to change wp prefix for custom post type only?

Tags: custom-post-types, plugins, database

I have Two domain for e.g

`example.com` (Database prefix `wpone_`)

`demo.example.com` (Database prefix `wptwo_`)

Database name: `myrestaurant`

Database is the same for two domain just only prefix different

I have one custom post type called `restaurants`.

**Question**: When i will post any restaurants in subdomain that entry i want in `wpone_posts` table( Means main domain table not in subdomain `wptwo_posts` table)

So here how to change database table prefix `wptwo_` to `wpone_` when wp_insert_post query execute?

Please give suggestion how to can i do?

Anyone have idea? Please do not down this question. Thanks

Comment: say it is only for inserting and it is possible,  what happens when you go to retrieve the posts? they will not be editable / visible / available from the subdomain site.

Comment: You cannot simply change the table prefix to achieve what you want. If you want to add restaurant from custom form or frontend you can make post request to main domain example.com.